# Does anyone know of a Windows product that will allow batch (command line or COM) "printing" of text to PDF with PDF stationery?

Tags: pdf, batch-file, com

I'm looking for a way to "print" some plain text and save it as a PDF file, overlay it onto some form of "stationery" (perhaps another PDF?) and save to a file.

I can do this in GUI mode with DeskPDF, fair enough, but the requirement I have is for a batch process (end-of-month invoice run) - so starting with a folder full of text files (invoice-1.txt, invoice-2.txt etc), produce another folder full of PDFs (invoice-1.pdf, invoice-2.pdf etc).

I can either run something as a command-line, by file-drop/folder monitoring, or ideally as COM- this is being run from a scripting system in a language called MAPPER.  Most PDF converters seem to install as pseudo-printers,  but printing to one from MAPPER in batch mode doesn't seem to work very well.

I can register the printer with MAPPER, but anything sent to it just seems to disappear.

The alternative would seem to be using something like LaTex, which is a hill I don't really want to climb!

Is there *anything* out there like this?  My Google-fu seems weak on this one.

Answer (score 1):

What i've been using is [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). Developped in java, but usage is from command line. You describe the pages in XML and use the binaries in FOP to convert them to PDF. I use the XML files as templates with variables in it that are replaced from script. Simple, stable and easy to use.

Comment: Yeah, FOP is one of the options I've been looking at.  But I had no idea you could just edit PDF files as above.

Answer (score 1):

I would use tex for this (latex, pdftex, luatex etc..). FOP or any other xsl-fo processor would be good. You could also use ghostscript with plain postscript files (using ps2pdf). This is also fairly straightforward. Finally if all else fails you can just write the PDF yourself.

With COM you can use word and indesign (tough they have a nasty administrator only restriction, also works much like xsl-fop). And lots of other tools.

Choice is yours really.

Here is a simple build your own windows batch example (the xref is broken but acrobat can handle this):

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%N IN (list.txt) DO (
    call :build_pfd "%%N" "%%O" "%%N"
)
exit /b

:build_pfd  %1 %2 %3 (name adress file)
(
echo.%%PDF-1. 4
echo.1 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Type /Catalog
echo./Outlines 2 0 R
echo./Pages 3 0 R
echo.^>^>
echo.endobj
echo.2 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Type /Outlines
echo./Count 0
echo.^>^>
echo.endobj
echo.3 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Type /Pages
echo./Kids [ 4 0 R ]
echo./Count 1
echo.^>^>
echo.endobj
echo.4 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Type /Page
echo./Parent 3 0 R
echo./MediaBox [ 0 0 595 420]
echo./Contents 5 0 R
echo./Resources ^<^< /ProcSet 6 0 R
echo./Font ^<^< /F1 7 0 R ^>^>
echo.^>^>
echo.^>^>
echo.endobj
echo.5 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Length 73 ^>^>
echo.stream
echo.BT
echo./F1 24 Tf
echo.300 300 Td
echo.^( %~1 ^) Tj
echo.ET
echo.BT
echo.300 276 Td
echo.^( %~2 ^) Tj
echo.ET
echo.endstream
echo.endobj
echo.6 0 obj
echo.[ /PDF /Text ]
echo.endobj
echo.7 0 obj
echo.^<^< /Type /Font
echo./Subtype /Type1
echo./Name /F1
echo./BaseFont /Helvetica
echo./Encoding /MacRomanEncoding
echo.^>^>
echo.endobj
echo.xref
echo.0 8
echo.0000000000 65535 f
echo.0000000009 00000 n
echo.0000000074 00000 n
echo.0000000120 00000 n
echo.0000000179 00000 n
echo.0000000364 00000 n
echo.0000000466 00000 n
echo.0000000496 00000 n
echo.trailer
echo.^<^< /Size 8
echo./Root 1 0 R
echo.^>^>
echo.startxref
echo.625
echo.%%%%EOF
) ^> %3.pdf
```

Assumes you have the list.txt

```
Bob the Builder;On TV
Spiderman;At Daily Bugle
```

**Edit:** Some clarification to the above. While PDF is possible to make as involved as possible, by compression the data in binary format. The base functionality of it is pretty simple, and resembles postscript quite a bit. You can find more or less all information that you ever want to know in the address:

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

And the file I generate is pretty much the same file as in the simple text examples. The file itself contains of several blocks and the last block is a quick reference so that you dont need to read the entire file. It contains offsets for each block for quick browsing of the file. This section is broken but because the file is so small it does not matter as its unlikely to be needed for random look up.

Now you can pretty easily put 2 blocks on the same page, this means that you can print one page with whatever PDF generating system you wish and hand craft your own section on top and modify only that. Hope this helps. See "G.6 Updating Example" in the pdf linked (no the additions dont need to be annotations).

Basically you search for the pages /Contents directive and change it from

```
/Contents id1 ver1 R
```

Where id1 and ver1 are arbitrary numbers pointing the the object in question. Append your own object as the next free id number and change the /Contents to

```
/Contents [id1 ver1 R youID 0 R]
```

This is how you could do it.

Comment: Is that actually building a PDF file from a batch script?  Is it really as simple as that?

Comment: Ye gods, it works!  I had no idea it was as simple as that.

If I can figure out how to add a background image to that, I could create the PDFs directly from MAPPER.

Could you deconstruct that batch file a little?  There are a bunch of what looks like arbitrary numbers there....

Comment: LOL. I'm not really serous about the example I just wanted to make it for the lulz, because I can. I can see that you had the WTF moment I was trying to convey. I added some info for you to follow. :) But, yes it would be good to not depend on huge pieces of software just to generate simple things. One should really try to pen files in text editor more often (sometimes after decompressing them as if they were zip files)

Comment: I have a background which is basically just a scan of the stationery required, all I need to do is to overlay some text in the right places.  The platform I use has its own scripting language, so I could plausibly create PDFs directly.  The tricky bit is putting in the logo- it generates an "object" full of binary characters, which are a pain to handle in MAPPER.  But it may still be possible....